# Getting on flutter web "502 Bad Gateway -Nginx" using keycloak authentication with openid_client

Tags: flutter, keycloak

I'm trying to log in with Keycloak using the plugin openid_client. The issue I am facing is that when the user clicks on the button the Keycloak page was open successfully but when the user adds his credentials the response after login was null and the web page shows
"502 Bad Gateway -Nginx"
and the issue I'm facing is on the flutter web. And I'm using a browser example.

my code

```
authenticate() async{

    // create the client
    var uri="https://example.com/auth/realms/jhipster"
    var clientId = 'test';
    var scopes = List<String>.of(['openid', 'profile']);
    var issuer = await Issuer.discover(uri);
    var client = new Client(issuer, clientId);
    
    // create an authenticator
    var authenticator = new Authenticator(client, scopes: scopes);
    
    // get the credential
    var c = await authenticator.credential;
    
    if (c==null) {
      // starts the authentication
      authenticator.authorize(); // this will redirect the browser
    } else {
      // return the user info
      return await c.getUserInfo();
    }
}
```

Please help me I did not understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is your uri variable in quotes?

Comment: yes. I forget to add while creating question.